# Dropdown list to show records isn't working

Tags: jquery, datatable

i have the following code which performs a filter on my datatable.

```
$("a").click(function(event){
   $("#datepicker").val('',3);
oTable.fnFilter(this.InnterHtml,3);
```

Ok, so this is clearing this date picker text box, and then applying a specific filter based on what was selected in the a href tag.

My problem, now, is that when i use the drop down menu to show 'ALL' records, it doesn't work. How do i clear all filters from the datatable, and return it to it's default state.

Here is the complete JQuery Code.

```
           $(document).ready(function () {
           var oTable;
           function renderDetailTable(result) {
               var dtDetailData = [];
               $.each(result, function () {
                   dtDetailData.push([
                       this.Sender,
                       this.MessageDate,
                       this.MessageTime,
                       this.Reference,
                       this.MessageType,
                       this.Receiver,
                       this.ValueDate,
                       this.Currency,
                       this.Amount


                   ]);
               });


               $.datepicker.regional[""].dateFormat = 'dd/mm/yy';
               $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['']);

               oTable = $('#tblMessageDetail').dataTable({
                   "aaData": dtDetailData,
                   "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25,50, 100, -1], [10, 25,50, 100, "ALL"]],
                   "asStripClasses": null,
                   "iDisplayLength": 10,
                   //"aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]],
                   "bJQueryUI": true,
                   "bFilter": true,
                   //"bAutoWidth": false,
                   //"bProcessing": true,
                   // "sDom": 'RC<"clear">lfrtip',
                   "sDom": 'RC<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>',

                   "aoColumnDefs": [
                       {"bVisible": false, "aTargets": [11,12,13,14]}
                   ],


                   //Scrolling .......
                   "sScrollY": "250px",
                   "sScrollX": "100%",
                   "sScrollXInner": "100%",
                   "bScrollCollapse": true,

                   //Dynamic Language .......
                   "oLanguage": {
                       "sZeroRecords": "There are no messages that match your search criteria",
                       "sLengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page&nbsp;&nbsp;",
                       "sInfo": "Displaying _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ records",
                       "sInfoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 records",
                       "sInfoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)",
                       "sEmptyTable": 'No Rows to display.....!',
                       "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
                   },
                   "oSearch": {
                       "sSearch": "",
                       "bRegex": false,
                       "bSmart": true
                   }
               });
           }

           $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: 'Default.aspx/GetMessageDetail',
               data: '{}',
               contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function (response) {
                   //console.log(response);
                   //alert(response.d);
                   renderDetailTable(response.d);
               },
               error: function (errMsg) {
                   $('#errorMessage').text(errMsg);
               }
           });

           $("#datepicker").datepicker({
               "onSelect": function (date) {
                   oTable.fnFilter(date, 1);
               }
           }).keyup(function () {
               oTable.fnFilter('');
               oTable.fnFilter(this.value, 1);
           });

           $(".reference").click(function (event) {
               event.preventDefault();
               $("#datepicker").val('');
                oTable.fnFilter('',1);
                oTable.fnFilter(this.innerHTML, 3);
           });

           $("#resetTable").click(function (event) {
              // event.preventDefault();
               alert("clicked");
              // oTable.fnResetAllFilters();
           }); 
       });
```

the drop down list is part of the datatable

Answer (score 0):

If there is no more special thing in your code, that the default filter should be like this:

```
$("a").click(function(event){
   $("#datepicker").val('',3);
oTable.fnFilter('');
```

If it doesn't work then you can check [this](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnFilterClear). try to use  `fnFilterClear`
Add that plug-in code and write below code:

```
oTables.fnResetAllFilters();
```

Comment: it's the dropdown list of the actual datatable that isn't working. if i apply any filtering, using either the date picker, or as is in my example a <a> tag

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that you add the filter to a column, I updated my answer.

Comment: ok, i've added the plug and called it as specified - but no joy. whenever i selected teh drop down list to show 'ALL' records, nothing happens

Comment: if i place a button above the table and then call the fnResetAllFilters then it works. But this seems to be a little over kill. Not sure why the drop down would stop working

Comment: what code do you need OQJF - this is standard datatable functionality that appears to not work if a fnFilter is applied.

Comment: is this all you code? when you select 'ALL' from dropdown list, you use this code?  at that time, you should call: oTables.fnResetAllFilters();  to remove the filter, not use ALl to do the filter.